# Laravel 5 + Excel + Lang Facade

Tags: excel, laravel, internationalization, lang

I've got an issue with the use of the Lang Facade in cobination with the Excel Export. The following code works as expected, it generates the Excel file as expected, but when I try to add the languages files the file seems to be corrupted and Microsoft Excel won't open it.

This is working perfect:

```
$details_toprow = array(
            "Ref",
            "Order Num",
            "Your order num",
            "Description",
            "Colour",
            "Units",
            "Price"
        );


        \Excel::create($filename, function ($excel) use ($shipment, $shipment_lines, $shipment_boxes, $headers, $details_toprow) {
            $excel->sheet('shipment', function ($sheet) use ($shipment, $shipment_lines, $shipment_boxes, $headers, $details_toprow)  {
                $objDrawing = new \PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
                $objDrawing->setPath(public_path(getAssetsPath().'/img/logo_extranet.png')); //your image path
                $objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');
                $objDrawing->setWorksheet($sheet);
                $sheet->row(2,$details_toprow);
                $sheet->mergeCells('A1:G1');
                $sheet->setHeight(1, 50);

                $row = 3;
                foreach($shipment_lines as $item)
                {
                    $sheet->row($row, array(
                        $item->getReference (),
                        $item->getOrderNumber(),
                        $item->getCustomOrderNumber(),
                        html_entity_decode($item->getReferenceDescription(false)),
                        $item->getColorDescription(),
                        $item->getQuantity (),
                        $item->getPrice ()
                    ));
                    $row++;
                }

                $row++;
                $row++;
                $second_box = $row;

                $sheet->row($row, array(
                    "Box number",
                    "Order Num",
                    "Your order num",
                    "Reference",
                    "Description",
                    "Color",
                    "Units",
                    "Ref s/cj",
                    "P/C Est.",
                    "Pc/Real"
                ));
                $row++;
                foreach($shipment_boxes as $item)
                {
                    $line = $item->getLine();
                    $order_num = null;
                    $order_custom_num = null;
                    $reference = null;
                    $description = null;
                    $color_description = null;
                    $units = null;
                    $rfscj = 1;
                    $pcest = $item->peso_estimado;;
                    $pcreal = $item->peso_real;;

                    if ($line)
                    {
                        $order_num = $line->getOrderNumber();
                        $order_custom_num = $line->getCustomOrderNumber();
                        $reference = $line->getReference();
                        $description = $line->getReferenceDescription(false);
                        $color_description = $line->getColorDescription();
                        $units = $line->getQuantity();


                    }
                    $sheet->row($row, array(
                        $item->caja_ID,
                        $order_num,
                        $order_custom_num,
                        $reference,
                        $description,
                        $color_description,
                        $units,
                        $rfscj,
                        $pcest,
                        $pcreal
                    ));
                    $row++;
                }
                $sheet->cells('A2:J2', function($cells) {
                    $cells->setFontColor('#ffffff');
                    $cells->setFontWeight('bold');
                    $cells->setBackground('#3A3A3A');
                });
                $sheet->cells('A1:J1', function($cells) {
                    $cells->setFontColor('#ffffff');
                    $cells->setFontWeight('bold');
                    $cells->setBackground('#3A3A3A');
                });
                $sheet->cells('A'.$second_box.':J'.$second_box.'', function($cells) {
                    $cells->setFontColor('#ffffff');
                    $cells->setFontWeight('bold');
                    $cells->setBackground('#3A3A3A');
                });
            });

        })->export('xls');
    }
```

If I change the values of the first array in the code to:

```
$details_toprow = array(
        Lang::get("extranet-shipments.ref"),
        Lang::get("extranet-shipments.order_num"),
        Lang::get("extranet-shipments.order_num_alt"),
        Lang::get("extranet-shipments.description") ,
        Lang::get("extranet-shipments.color") ,
        Lang::get("extranet-shipments.units") ,
        Lang::get("extranet-shipments.price")
    );
```

The only difference is the array values assigment, from "hardcoded" to load from Lang facade, the The excel file seems to be corrupted

Comment: Go to `php artisan tinker` and type `Lang::get("extranet-shipments.ref")`. Let us know what's the output of the command

Comment: It returns => "extranet-shipments.ref"

Comment: This is the content of resources/lang/es/extranet-shipment.php

Comment: <?php
    return [
    "ref"=>"Ref",
    "date"=>"Fecha Albarán",
    "date_delivery"=>"Fecha entrega",
    "client"=>"Cliente",
    "transport"=>"Transporte",
    "order_num"=>"Nº Pedido",
    "order_num_alt"=>"Su nº de pedido",
    "description"=>"Descripción",
    "color"=>"Color",
    "units"=>"Und.",
    "price"=>"PVP",
    "shipment_num"=>"ALBARÁN Nª",
    "xls_export"=>"Exportar albarán en Excel",
    "total"=>"Total",
    "goback"=>"Volver atrás",
    "print"=>"Imprimir albaran",
    ];

Answer (score 0):

I notice that there was a whitespace that was causing this not to work in the lang files.

I guest it was sending the headers before Excel had finished his job and that amy corrup the file.

Thanks for your help